# iOS - Objects being released?

Tags: iphone, ios, release

I have the following piece of code:

```
Dummy *dummy = [[Dymmy alloc] initWithDictionary:dummyData];
DummyTableItem *dummyTableItem = [DummyTableItem itemWithDummy: dummy];
[_data addObject: dummyTableItem];
```

The init functions are as follows:

```
+ (id) itemWithDummy: (Dummy *) dummy {
  DummyTableItem *item = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
  item.dummy = dummy;
  return item;
}

- (id) init {
  self = [super init];
  if( self ) {
    dummy = nil;
  }
  return self;
}
```

with dummy declared as (nonatomic, retain)

And Dummy:

```
@synthesize name=_name;

- (id) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
  self = [super init];

  if( self != nil ) {
    if( [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] )
  _name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
  }

  return self;
}
```

with name again declared as (nonatomic, retain)

When I am trying to access later on the dummyTableItem.dummy.name to set it to a UILabel I am getting a "-[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5b37a10"

Am I doing something completely wrong with the retained objects? What am I missing here? Also in the first part of code should I release the dummyTableItem after adding it to _data (which is an NSMutableArray?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem inside Dummy's @implementation :

```
@synthesize name=_name;

- (id) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _name = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] retain]; //retain it :)
  }
  return self;
}
```

Since you declared `name` as retain you should own it (That is why I added `retain` when assigning it). 
Furthermore, you don't need to check `if( [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] )` because `_name = [nil retain];` is `nil` anyways :)

Comment: You could also use the setter of the `name` property: `self.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];`